# Start a groovy script directly from its url

Tags: command-line, groovy

I have a script that is available on the web, and I want to run it directly by entering its url, instead of downloading it and running later. Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Presumably you want to run the script on the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to run a groovy script from a URL from the command line, you can do the following:

```
groovy -e 'evaluate( new URL( "http://yoururl.com/yourscript.groovy" ).text )'
```

#### Edit

[Since Groovy 1.8.3](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4740), it is possible to do:

```
groovy http://myserver/myScript.groovy
```

Obviously care must be taken with doing this either way...  Running stuff straight off the internet is never best advised ;-)